# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Data.DataRow>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, list

I have the following code:

```
   List<String> rows = 
     allDetails.Tables[3].AsEnumerable().OrderBy(dr => dr.Field<string>  ("JobTitle")).ToList();
```

The error is:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Data.DataRow>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`DataTable.AsEnumerable()` returns an `IEnumerable<DataRow>` which you can use for LINQ queries like yours. But you cannot use `ToList` on it and expect that it is a `List<String>`. Therefore you have to select the string-field:

```
List<String> orderedJobTitles = allDetails.Tables[3].AsEnumerable()
    .OrderBy(dr => dr.Field<string>("JobTitle"))
    .Select(dr => dr.Field<string>("JobTitle"))
    .ToList();
```

You could also select the field before you order by it if you don't need the `DataRow` anyway:

```
List<String> orderedJobTitles = allDetails.Tables[3].AsEnumerable()
    .Select(dr => dr.Field<string>("JobTitle"))
    .OrderBy(jobTitle => jobTitle)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I want to sort gridview based on JobTitle then what i do.

Comment: @user3392666: you should ask another question if you have another question. You should also provide the code and the problem you had with your current approach. This question is about your conversion error.

Comment: <asp:GridView ID="gvDetails" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                                        AllowPaging="True" Width="747px" CssClass="GridviewTabulardata1" 
                                         GridLines="None" onpageindexchanging="gvDetails_PageIndexChanging" 
                                        onrowdatabound="gvDetails_RowDataBound" AllowSorting="True" DataKeyNames="JobTitle" >

Comment: @user3392666: you should ask  *another* question, not edit this question. A question on SO is not like a thread in a forum. Ask specific questions, if it is solved accept it. If you have different questions ask a new question. On that way they are not in danger of getting too broad and they will be most helpful for others